# ftp_get works on localhost, but not on production server

Tags: php, ftp

I am using ftp_get to fetch a file from another ftp server.

My code works perfectly on my local WAMP server, but when I apply it to my actual web hosting, the connection fails.

```
$conn = ftp_connect('ftp.server.com') or die('Could not connect');
ftp_login($conn,'myusername','mypassword');
$local_file = 'new/two.txt';
$remote_file = 'games/minecraft/craftbukkit/plugins/VisitCounter/config.yml';
$get = ftp_get($conn,$local_file,$remote_file,FTP_ASCII);

if ($get){

    echo 'Connection Successful';
} else{

    echo 'Connection failure';
}

exec($get);
ftp_close($conn);
```

I'm thinking that something required to establish a ftp connection must be disabled on my web server.

Can any of you assist?

Thanks,

Jared

Comment: Maybe ftp port is blocked on your hosting?

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Could it be IP-based connection filtering on the remote server?  i.e. Your dev box IP has been whitelisted but your web host IP has not?  Can you ssh into the server and use a command line `ftp` to connect?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I am getting no errors, just connection failure.

Comment: @leftclickben My web hosts don't support SSH (I know, it sucks)

Comment: Time for a new web host then.

Comment: Enable error reporting to see the errors. Is `ftp.server.com` the same  in both scripts?

Comment: @CodeCaster All of the details are identical in both scripts. I will try turning on error reporting now.

Answer (score 3):

Your server is not in a passive mode,You just need to  turns on  passive mode of your server using the php function as :-

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);   

// login with username and password

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// turn passive mode on

$ps = ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Gives NULL after Taking FTP to passive mode